# be a point taker?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

What does "point taker" mean in the following? Is it natural English?

> Doing X is a **point taker** on most standardized tests.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

It can translate to:

> Doing X will earn you points on most standardized tests.

Personally, I don't see it being used often but it's mostly used in the context of sport/game such as to refer to someone who is a goal-scorer.

> "He is one of the best point takers in the team."